# Cloudinary jquery upload is not saving image_id correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary with jquery to directly upload an image from the browser in a RoR app.  I think I've followed the instructions from [here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser) pretty much exactly.

The image upload is working, but the params[:image_id] that's returned appears to have the signature appended after a # sign, like so:

```
"image_1_id"=>"image/upload/v1383951287/foobar.jpg#b023156dfebede65......."}
```

So this ends up being saved on the model.  Then, when I try to retrieve the image using:

```
<%= cl_image_tag(@model.image_1_id) %>
```

as suggested in the docs, not only does the url have the signature appended, it has also duplicated part of the path in front, like this:

```
http://res.cloudinary.com/.../image/upload/v1/image/upload/v1383951287/foobar.jpg%23b023156d...
```

Obviously this link doesn't work, but if you remove the duplicated path and the signature from the end, it works.

I'm not using CarrierWave, partly because there's little (no?) instruction in the docs about how or why you would use it with the non-server-side image upload.  Also I'm using a form_for for the image and other attributes, could that be the problem?  Form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @model do |f| %>
...
<%= f.cl_image_upload(:image_1_id) %>
...
<% end %>
```

Any help greatly appreciated. I'm pretty new to this stuff so it's likely something simple I have missed.  But it's worth saying that there are no errors in the console and JS files appear to be loading correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The [photo album](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/tree/master/samples/photo_album) sample project in the cloudinary_gem samples folder shows an example of how to use Cloudinary with CarrierWave integration for both direct and through-server uploads.

The returned value you're seeing is structured as it should. This is how a preloaded file URI is returned from Cloudinary. If you don't want to use CarrierWave you can still use [PreloadedFile](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem/blob/master/lib/cloudinary/preloaded_file.rb). Feeding what you receive from Cloudinary into `PreloadedFile`'s constructor can serve the double purpose of both allowing you to validate the upload using the returned signature (see `valid?`) and translate that value into something that can be fed into the `cl_image_tag`, (see `identifier`).

You can either keep the full returned URI and translate it when using it or store the translated value into your DB.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should save your model. In order to use cl_image_tag properly

```
if params[:image_id].present?
  preloaded = Cloudinary::PreloadedFile.new(params[:image_id])         
  raise "Invalid upload signature" if !preloaded.valid?
  @category.image_id = preloaded.identifier
end
```